# iPhone 6s uncharged at 30% battery

Tags: battery, iphone, charge

So I have an iPhone 6s for about a year now, and a week ago or so it uncharged (died) at 30% about. Then today it uncharged again at 30%, I tried turning it on right after but it showed me the black screen you get when iPhone uncharges (with the red battery level), in 5 min I tried turning it on again and it successfully turned on showing me 34%, but then died again in a few seconds. What could be the problem and what is the possible solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has determined that a very small number of iPhone 6s devices may unexpectedly shut down. This is not a safety issue and only affects devices within a limited serial number range that were manufactured between September and October 2015.

If you have experienced this issue, please use the [serial number checker](https://www.apple.com/support/iphone6s-unexpectedshutdown/) to see if your iPhone 6s is eligible for a battery replacement, free of charge.

Comment: I just found out I'm eligible for the battery replacement, is that the issue for sure?

Comment: Yes, I experienced the same issues. After the battery was replaced I did not experienced it again.